# Paquete metadata o spDataLarge is not available

Tags: r

Me gustaría obtener el mapa de España donde se muestren los diferentes usos que se le dan a su cubierta terrestre (en terminos de vegetación; bosques, cultivos etc) mediante R.
He intentado hacerlo con el paquete Metadata, ya que según esta página ( https://pakillo.github.io/R-GIS-tutorial/ ) dice que es el paquete destinado para tal fin, pero no logro encontrar información sobre ese paquete

Por otro lado, en esta página explica como hacerlo (https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html) pero también parte de un paquete inexistente (spDataLarge).

Intento instalar el paquete Metadata o spDataLarge y no lo encuentra, ¿alguien sabe como instalarlo o donde puede encontrarlo?

Si existe otra manera de hacerlo u otro paquete lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Tienes la reputación suficiente para saber [ask]. Por favor, edita tu pregunta agregando lo que has intentado y explica el error o dificultad eapecífica. Saludos

Comment: No Mauricio, normalmente pregunto sobre errores derivados de un intento de programar un análisis. En este supuesto quiero obtener el tipo de mapa que enuncio en el post y solo he obtenido la información de un supuesto paquete llamado Metadata el cual ya ni existe. Es por eso por lo que este post parece algo raro y escueto pero no parto de más información, de aqui el tipo de pregunta que hago

Comment: Los paquetes que mencionanas no están en CRAN. Pará metadata puedes [descargar] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Metadata/index.html) las versiones ". tz" archivadas e instalarlas del archivo local. Y para spDataLarge hay algunas instrucciones en su repo de [github] (https://github.com/Nowosad/spDataLarge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El paquete efectivamente hoy no existe en CRAN, una situación lamentablemente  común. Voy a elaborar una respuesta por que me parece útil ver que hacer cuando nos encontramos con estos casos y queremos tratar de ubicar esa funcionalidad que ha desaparecido.

¿Podemos rastrear la historia de un paquete desaparecido?. Es posible, hay que hacer un poco de arqueología informática. Veamos:

- Como te decía, hoy en la lista de paquetes de [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html) no hay ninguna referencia a este paquete
- Podemos intentar de forma explícita buscar la página del paquete, agregando a la URL `paquete/index.html`, por ejemplo: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Metadata/index.html
- Y hemos tenido suerte, ya sabemos que alguna vez existió `Metadata` en CRAN:

> Package ‘Metadata’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

- Eventualmente podríamos ir al enlace al archivo de la última versión y probar instalar el paquete descargando alguno de los archivos `tar.gz`. La instalación desde un paquete de código fuentes es bastante simple:

  ```
  install.packages("/Metadata_1.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
  ```
- Este paquete en particular evidentemente parece *"deprecado"* ya que requiere otras librería que hoy tampoco están disponibles en CRAN
- Otra cosa que podemos hacer, es intentar buscar la historia del paquete, muchos dejan de estar en CRAN pero sus autores los siguen manteniendo en github, o bien hay paquetes que cambian de nombre o su funcionalidad se incorpora a otro.
- El documento que comentas, tiene una fecha de publicación del año 2013
- Vamos a [webarchive.org](https://web.archive.org/) y buscamos la versión de ese entonces de la página de los paquetes y, bingo!, tenemos la [información del paquete](https://web.archive.org/web/20130115074449/http://cran.r-project.org/)
- Sabemos que ese paquete lo desarrolló Steven Mosher, que mantiene un [blog activo](https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/) al cual eventualmente podríamos contactar
- También tenemos el paquete en [el github de CRAN](https://github.com/cran/Metadata) pero el último commit es de hace 9 años, mirando un poco el código fuente, hay algunas urls dónde se descarga información que hoy ya no existen, por lo que la conclusión, podría ser que el paquete ya quedó en desuso, por falta de interés o por que su funcionalidad ya fue incorporada a algún otro proyecto, podemos ver que el autor tiene varios [repositorios](https://github.com/stevenmosher) pero ninguno se llama `Metadata`